# React native : Android device back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting one issue on android device back button. When I'm login to the app and go to home screen and from home screen, if I'm pressing device back button then it's redirected to me login screen again instead of the background.

Please help me how app go to background state when I'm pressing back button once app successful login in the app i.e. from home screen.

Here My code,

**Login.js**

```
//Click on login button call this method
  home()
  {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Home', { name: 'Home'});

  }
```

**Home.js:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount()
{
  console.disableYellowBox = true;
  console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName);

    this.callapi();
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
  if (this.props.navigation.state.routeName == 'Home') {
  //  this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
//  BackHandler.exitApp()
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: What type of router are you using?

Comment: I'm using react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are pushing the user to the homepage when the login returns true. You have to reset the router's stack instead.

I personally use `react-native-navigation` by Wix and never used `react-navigation`. But by looking at their docs, it shows that you can reset the stack by adding this block of code instead:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

More info can be found [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset)

Comment: Doing same, but not working, I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I can't fully help you if you do not post some of your code.

Comment: Okay here is my code:

Login.js:

  home()
  {
    
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Home', { name: 'Home'});

  }

Comment: Home.js:
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}
componentWillMount()
{
  console.disableYellowBox = true;
  console.log(this.props.navigation.state.routeName);

  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
  if (this.props.navigation.state.routeName == 'Home') {
  //  this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
//  BackHandler.exitApp()
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
    }
   
}

Comment: Add login.js too.

Comment: OK... Add the reset code from my answer inside login.js. Delete the `navigate()` part.